# Unit test for scripts in one git repository that make calls to function in other git repository

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I have a git repository that has scripts which only make API calls. These scripts are like bots and poller scripts. These scripts are node.js scripts.
The APIs which these scripts call are present in a separate git repository.
We have structured this so that we do not have tight coupling.

I was wondering how can I write a simple unit test for the bots and poller scripts and mock the function calls. If these scripts would have been in the same repository as the APIs they call, it would be simple. But in this case, it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Mocha Testing Restful API Endpoints and Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972078/node-js-mocha-testing-restful-api-endpoints-and-code-coverage)

Comment: there are many Stack Overflow questions regarding the testing of node.js functions which make calls to external APIs.  which of them have you researched and why do they not solve your specific problem?

Comment: Thank you Dan! Let me try the approach mentioned in the link you shared. I am still researching, and as I am new to node js I was not able to make much progress. Thank you for helping